# Multicore ARM Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, arm, multiprocessing

I am working on a program in ARM Assembly and C that runs with no OS. I am basing my code on [these examples](https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi).

I am looking into using all four cores on my ARM board and didn't know where to start. I have seen explanations of how this works in x86, but I haven't come up with anything for ARM assembly in my search. Where should I start to develop multicore ARM assembly? Could somebody provide a basic example that shows this?

EDIT: I am using an Allwinner H3 CPU and I am already planning to use four different programs. I have seen [this](https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi/tree/ec6b9f1b6a2d38d56f0a4a43683db1be01280ae2/multi00). However, after doing some research, I cannot find the mailbox addresses for the cores in the datasheet.

Comment: You should start with reading about threads.

Comment: Pretty sure I cover that somewhere in those examples.  Assembly vs other language has nothing to do with it and this is not a threading thing.  You have four processors.  Write four programs.  Whenever you have to share something (a peripheral) use standard techniques for that (ldrex/strex are specifically there for you to do this) or you make one the master of that peripheral and use a shared ram space or other to communicate (a mailbox) between cores so the master of that peripheral can perform tasks for the other cpus.

Comment: The stock bootloader (if you dont have a config.txt) isolates the cores for you and you have three mailbox registers you use to provide the entry address for the cores other than zero.  Again you write four programs one for each.  Problem is if you consider it a problem you are in HYP mode and it is a RPITA to get back to SVC completely.

Comment: If you prefer SVC mode then you have to use config.txt to tell it to boot from 0x00000000, and then you have to make the code isolate the cores, this is provided in my examples as well as other folks examples.  and then you aim the four cores into the four programs.

Comment: at the end of the day multicore programs are just...programs...for multiple cores.  so multiple programs.  the operating system manages mutiple programs whether you are multicore or single.  baremetal you manage the multiple programs, in this case you have four cores so start with four programs, thats free, then if you want more programs you have to deal with making a scheduler for each cpu just like you would on a single core machine.   single core or multiple you still have to manage/share the peripherals which an operating system (and drivers) would do

Comment: assembly has almost nothing to do with this other than ldrex/strex and perhaps a few coprocessor items if you use them.  you can do everything in C and just have asm functions for ldrex/strex and the few other items.

Comment: You might want to consider one of the free RTOS kernels for ARM that support multicore.

Comment: The raspberrypi.org bare metal forum is actually a very good resource for using this chip/core, better than stackoverflow for baremetal on the raspi.